# Where to get device type constants description?

Tags: c++, linux, netlink

I'm getting the information about system network devices through netlink socket.
I'm parsing three message types `RTM_NEWLINK`, `RTM_DELLINK`, `RTM_GETLINK` defined in the `ifinfomsg` structure.

```
struct ifinfomsg {
    unsigned char  ifi_family; /* AF_UNSPEC */
    unsigned short ifi_type;   /* Device type */
    int            ifi_index;  /* Interface index */
    unsigned int   ifi_flags;  /* Device flags  */
    unsigned int   ifi_change; /* change mask */
};
```

the definition is from here http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html

But there are no description for the device type field `ifi_type`, where can I found the constants that describes the possible values?

there are no description even here
http://www.foxprofr.com/rfc/RFC3549-LINUX-NETLINK-AS-AN-IP-SERVICES-PROTOCOL/3549.aspx

Now I know that `1` is ethernet and `772` is loopback, but I'd like to know all possible values.
May be the answer is very obvious but google doesn't want to tell me anything usefull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `/usr/include/net/if_arp.h`, you will find the constants there as `ARPHRD_*`. If you want to make your life somewhat easier, check out **[libnl](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/)** if you don't use it already.

Comment: yep, there is even a transform function: Link Layer Type (16bit)
Currently only used in kernel→user messages to report the link layer type of a link. The value corresponds to the ARPHRD_* defines found in <linux/if_arp.h>. Translation from/to strings can be done using the functions nl_llproto2str()/nl_str2llproto().

Comment: @ldx: Care to share where you found out about this?

Comment: I've used libnl in the past. Probably I had to dig into the source, I don't remember.